# Construct inequality comfort to condition n ≥ -2 for each n ∈ Z. Than prove that inequality by mathematics induction...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I tried to formulate inequation by constructing an quadratic form by taking one of the solutions x1 = -2 but need a bit help what should be the x2 that i need to take, or should i change the form of inequality (p.s linear or some other form).

p.s I can use induction well when inequality is constructed.

Thank you so much in advance :)